# Editor option missing under Appearance

Tags: editor

I want to edit my default color pallet.  When I go to Appearance, I only get Theme, Customize, and Theme Editor.  I don't have the Editor option which allows me to change the default colors.  I checked the wp_config.php file and there is no define statement for the editor (default is false so no need to add a define).  I've disabled all plugins.  The default WP themes show the Editor option with or without the plugin's activation.

I just want to align the WP default colors with my CSS.

Comment: are you using a block theme or a classic theme?